# Combining algorithms for password storage?

Tags: hash, passwords, multiple-encryption, bcrypt, scrypt

Is it more secure to combine algorithms for password hashing, for example, Scrypt, Bcrypt, SHA-3, etc.? If an attacker wants to use dedicated hardware, he would need one for each algorithm. However, I know having multiple algorithms increases the probability of having bugs and leaks.

If having multiple algorithms for EACH password can create leaks, what about having different algorithms for different passwords: If the attacker only has hardware for Bcrypt, he can't brute force passwords hashed with Scrypt.

EDIT : By combining, I mean, hash2(hash1(hash0(password))). In the second paragraph, I mean hash0(P0), hash1(P1), hash2(P2), hash0(P3), hash1(P4), hash2(P5).

EDIT : What about hash0(P0), hash1(P0), hash0(P1), hash1(P1), ... ?

Comment: How would you combine them? Hash every password using all hashes and store all the hashes? Chain the hashes? ... something else?

Comment: You seem to assume hardware acceleration is a magic bullet; it isn't. Pick a modern KDF and use an appropriate cost based on your threat assessment. You can further make stored hashes safer by using a secret [pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)) in addition to the salt.

Comment: If an attacker only has one type of harware, it is much worse for him if I use another algorithm than if I use pepper, they can just run it multiple times, and it wont be much more slower for a normal user. Pepper is very slow for both, multiple algorithm is much much slower for the attacker.

Comment: It seems we have a different definition of the pepper, in my case, your definition of the pepper can't be used as it is end to end encryption.

Comment: @SEJPM Both will work acctually.

Comment: The link I mentioned is pretty clear: a pepper is a long server-owned secret added to the plaintext password before hashing. Unlike a salt, it is **not** stored next to the hash and provides protection against leaks of the database contents (a common issue). Someone with just the hash and salt would have to brute force both the password and the pepper. With an appropriate length, no amount of hardware acceleration will help.

Comment: Yes I know, I read the article, my definition of the pepper was a very short (maybe 6 bits) value that is not stored ANYWHERE, neither in plaitext nor somewhere else in the database, to hash the password, both the attacker and the normal user have to test all combinations of pepper, for a 6 bit value, they have to hash 32 time in average.

Comment: @SEJPM However, as I said, in my case, it is end to end encryption, the server never encrypts or decrypts. So the pepper can't be used bacause it would have to be stored in the CLIENT files.

Comment: What is the name of my definition of the pepper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of different schemes may be somewhat advantageous with regard to certain custom hardware (ASICs), but I think that the disadvantages outweigh them.

- I assume that there is some kind of fixed time that is acceptable to the user. Nobody will use a procedure where she or he has to wait several minutes.
  Modern password hashing schemes are characterized by the fact that they are not only time intensive, but also memory-hard. To put it simply, a vector is created in RAM in the time acceptable to the user. If less time is available, this vector is smaller. Splitting the acceptable time over several password hashing schemes results in less time to generate the vector for each single scheme. So the whole process becomes less memory-hard.
- Password hashing schemes, like all cryptographic procedures, are potentially susceptible to side channel attacks. This applies, for example, to cache timing attacks. Several schemes offer more targets.
- And as the questioner has already correctly pointed out, the susceptibility to bugs is greater with several schemes.

I would rather rely on one scheme such as Argon2id and spend all available time to make this method as memory-hard as possible.